# Passing data frame as optional function parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way that I can pass a data frame as an optional input function parameter in Scala?
 Ex:

```
def test(sampleDF: DataFrame = df.sqlContext.emptyDataFrame): DataFrame = {


}


df.test(sampleDF)
```

Though I am passing a valid data frame here , it is always assigned to an empty data frame, how can I avoid this?

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. (Body of the function aside)

Comment: You have just set a default parameter for your function, if you pass a valid data frame to `test`, it should work. Why are you using `df.test` here? What is `df`?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can pass `dataframe` as a parameter to a function

lets say you have a `dataframe` as

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, 2, 3),
  (1, 2, 3)
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

which is

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1   |2   |3   |
|1   |2   |3   |
+----+----+----+
```

you can pass it to a function as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def test(sampleDF: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  sampleDF.select("col1", "col2") //doing some operation in dataframe
}

val testdf = test(df)
```

`testdf` would be

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|1   |2   |
|1   |2   |
+----+----+
```

**Edited**

As eliasah pointed out that @Garipaso wanted optional argument. This can be done by defining the function as

```
def test(sampleDF: DataFrame = sqlContext.emptyDataFrame): DataFrame = {
  if(sampleDF.count() > 0) sampleDF.select("col1", "col2") //doing some operation in dataframe
  else sqlContext.emptyDataFrame  
}
```

If we pass a valid dataframe as

```
test(df).show(false)
```

It will give output as

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|1   |2   |
|1   |2   |
+----+----+
```

But if we don't pass argument as

```
test().show(false)
```

we would get empty dataframe as

```
++
||
++
++
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Hi @RameshMaharjan, about performance and default behaviour: it is a copy or a reference? (like the classic problem of "array as parameter" is never clair when it is low or hight cost of coping reference or coping all data)