# Databricks: function with dataframe as a parameter (SCALA)

Tags: scala, databricks

How to create a function which has a dataframe as a parameter ? I hit the following problem
[image]

How to solve?? I tried "Dataframe" but still not ok

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to stackoverflow. Well the short answer to your question is - please learn Scala before programming in Scala and you will be able to create function with "Whatever" you need as a parameter. To any reader on stackoverflow, such question just show you as someone who just want to win that particular 100 meter race without even caring to learn to walk.

Comment: so what's your input ?

Comment: That comment exactly is my input. No more, no less. What you have asked should have been answered in first chapter of practically every scala book, or day 1 of learning Scala.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh If you feel there is an issue with the question flag it and let a moderator deal with the issue. There is no need to disparage someone who's reaching out for help. That being said @MichaelChau this question seems similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45050326/passing-data-frame-as-optional-function-parameter-in-scala). I believe you should be using `DataFrame`, not `Dataframe`. Please do some research on StackOverflow and other websites before posting to make sure you're not repeating a question.

Comment: @SkippyNBS Do you think that answering this question is even possible given his current knowledge of Scala ? I see too many such questions where people just want to "use" Spark without putting any effort in learning. Well at this point, I want to outright criticise (which I would have done if I was mentoring him in any capacity) him for not spending any time learning the language he is trying to program in. Here I am just trying to convey that instead of wasting his time in guessing the "mysteries" of the language, he can as well spend lesser time in learning it.

Answer (score 0):

@MichaelChau I recommend doing some research before posting your question, people tend to respond better if you can demonstrate the work you've already done to try and solve your problem. That being said (and I'm sorry this is a little late), the following code should answer your question:

```
%scala // sets the command language to scala, I'm testing this in a python notebook 

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame // this imports the DataFrame type

def writeToSQLWarehouse (df: DataFrame, tableName: String, mode: String) = {
  // I didn't write out all the options, but this should give you a starting place
  df.write
  .option("dbTable", tableName)
  .mode(mode)
  .save()
}
```

I got this information from the [databricks documentation page](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/introduction-to-dataframes-scala.html). Check it out if you any further questions.